# Modifying joomla mod_banner to count banner

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I'm using default joomla `mod_banner`. 
I'd like to modify the module so can give specific css class for each banner image, so if the module displaying 3 banner images, the first banner (image) will have `class="banner1"`, the second image will have `class="banner2"` the third image will have `class="banner3"` and so on.
How can I do that?

Comment: if i am not wrong then i think, `mod_banner()` produce the random images

Comment: Ah .. so do you have any other approach so I can get the give unique classto any image? Not necessarily in sequence from one to three, just have a unique class for each images. Thanks

Comment: checkout the modified answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decide to modify your `mod_banners` module, then just follow the steps:

1. Open the `/modules` from your root directory.
2. Find the directory named `mod_banners` in `modules/mod_banners`
3. Find out the tmpl directory `modules/mod_banners/tmpl`
4. `default.php` is the file that display the images into the frontend of you joomla website.

just edit this file. See the `img` tag into and just change whatever name you want to give the class..

**UPDATE :** Take a look on the given Codes:

```
// Add variable before
$unique_number = 1;
// Provide the Provides the images URL or related information
foreach($list as $item):
```

now just find out the `<img` tag and just add a class something like

```
<img class='banner-<?php echo $unique_number?>'
```

and at the end of the file findout the `endforeach;` and just add the code something like

```
<?php
$unique_number++;
endforeach;
?>
```

providing you the class name like `banner-1, banner-2, ....` etc.

**IMPORTANT**: If you notice on the top most of your `default.php` the module provide the images into an array, If you are familiar with the Joomla modules structures then you can modify it easily.

Comment: @dreamexploded happy yo help you ;)

Comment: There is only one problem with this answer - your edits will be wiped out when you update Joomla. Rather than editing modules/mod_banners/tmpl/default.php make a copy of it and place it in templates/YOUR TEMPLATE/html/mod_banners/default.php. This will override the standard file and will not be touched when you update Joomla.

Comment: @BrentFriar thanks a lot, didn't knew this feature, cause i have been used joomla 1.5 before 1 and half year ago.